# Writing test inside function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have two functions running at the same time(simultaneously). I want to write my test inside one of them. I mean I want to run my test's simultaneously with my other function. Because my other function creates fake data such as it creates votes if that turn is "night". So my test file is stated below. How can I run my test simultaneously with other function.

```
def function1():
    call_command('fake')

def function2():
    # some codes here
    # I also want to write my tests here because I need to fake command is running
    # while my test's running

thread1 = Thread(target=function1)
thread2 = Thread(target=function2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()  
time.sleep(10)
```

fake data generator is stated below

```
while room.status != 'Finished':
    if turn and turn.type == 'Day'
        sleep(0.5)
          to_be_killed = RoomPlayer.objects.filter(
        room=room).filter(alive=True).order_by("?")[0]
        Vote.objects.create(
           day=turn, voter=room_players[j], voted=to_be_killed)
```

Comment: I don't think this question is clear enough to be answerable. Anyway, there is no much sense in having test code inside a production function - you should check the concept of "mock" and "monkey patch" instead: you call your function, but the external resources it uses to "communicate with the World" - be it a file, or a network connection, are temporarily replaced by fake instances, for the test only.

Comment: I agree with @jsbueno are you refering to ```test``` as in testing functionality making sure your code does what it is supposed to do? Like unit tests? You do not run tests parallel/simultaniously to your application code. Your intentions are unclear what and why you are trying to do it this way?